Initialize each element of std::array from reference of another std::array
I have a class A:
class A {

};

and another class B:
class B {
public:
    explicit B(A &a) : aRef(a) {}
private:
    A &aRef;
};

I first init an array of A:
std::array<A, 2> As{};

Now I want to init an array of B of which each element is initialized with an element of A:
std::array<B, 2> Bs{B{As[0]}, B{As[1]}};

This one works. But as the array size grows, the readability decreases and I have to use another script to print the code for me. Is there a more elegant way to do this?
Declare Bs as an array of std::unique_ptr<B> will work. However, I want an array of B directly. I think a combination of templates and std::index_sequence might be the right direction.

FWIW a reference class member is normally not something you want.  It removes the assignment operators from the class.

@NathanOliver Yes, in this simplified example I'd better declare A as a member of B. However, in my case, I have another (array of) class C which also needs a reference to A. And that creates the problem.

You can often replace a reference with a pointer, or if you despise pointers a std::reference_wrapper

Most important aspect of members with reference type is dangling. Such objects must be consumed on the same line as they are created. Otherwise you'll triger UB.

auto Bs = std::apply([](auto&... args){ return std::array{B{args}...}; }, As);

